# What is the use of response.sendRedirect()?

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, response

while using `respone.sendRedirect("page.jsp")` it was showing `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, while in some pages it was executing properly. How can I avoid this exception? For more details I passed yesterday a question that was simillar to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`respone.sendRedirect` will throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException` if your response is already committed. You have either manually flush the buffer or it was automatically flushed because it was full. To avoid this, either increase the buffer size and make sure that you are not flushing it or call `respone.sendRedirect` early.

Comment: Buffer size example: `<%@ page buffer="256kb" autoFlush="false" %>`

Comment: Thanku sooooooo much Chandra Sir